# Rails cocoon-gem double nested forms "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) in my rails app and trying to double-nest forms.

The first "link_to_add_association" adds the valve_fields partial which contains another "link_to_add_association" it gives this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass):
21:                         .line_items
22:                                 =f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |line_item|
23:                                         =render 'line_item_fields', :f => line_item
24:                 //error line//  =link_to_add_association "add line", f, :line_items
```

I haven't done anything differently for the first link than the second but for some reason it won't work

```
//Rfq controller 
def rfq_params
  params.require(:rfq).permit(
    :quote_number,:rep_id, :owner, :customer_id, :customer_name, :end_user_list, :application_list, :due, :ship_date, :is_budgetary, :notes, :mandatory_due_date, 
    valves_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :productline, :discwedge, :valvetype, :valveends, :valvematerial, :valveconfig, :valvenotes,
    line_items_attributes: [
    :tag, :qty, :size, :class, :operator, :trim, :_destroy
    ]
    ])
end


//form partial:

  .valves
    =f.fields_for :valves do |valve|
      =render 'valve_fields', :f => valve
    =link_to_add_association 'add valve', f, :valves, "data-association-insertion-traversal" => "next"

//valve partial
.line_items
    =f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |line_item|
        =render 'line_item_fields', :f => line_item
    =link_to_add_association "add line", f, :line_items
```

Comment: Can you update post with code for your link_to_add_association helper method?

Comment: @steveklein link_to_add_association is part of the cocoon gem found here
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb

Comment: @steveklein So I'm not sure why this fixed it but I changed the "line_item" attributes to have "valve_" as a prefix and it works.  So before it had an attribute "class" and now it's "valve_class". If you can explain why I'll give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `rfq_params` method, you are having `line_items_attributes` inside `valve_attributes`. It means `line_items` are `nested` inside of `valve`, so in your form you should change this line `f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |line_item|` to `valve.simple_fields_for :line_items do |line_item|`.